# Why are functional analysts interested in not only the point spectrum of $f$, but also, its spectrum?

Tags: functional-analysis, motivation

Suppose $\mathbb{K}\in \{\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C}\},$ that $X$ is a Banach space over $\mathbb{K}$, and that $f : X \leftarrow X$ is a bounded linear transform. Then the *spectrum* of $f$ is defined as the set of all $\lambda \in \mathbb{K}$ such that $f - (\lambda \cdot \mathrm{id}_X)$ fails to be invertible in the category $\mathbf{Ban}$ of Banach spaces and bounded linear transforms, and the *point spectrum* of $f$ is defined as the set of all eigenvalues of $f$, i.e. the set of all $\lambda \in \mathbb{K}$ such that $f-(\lambda \cdot \mathrm{id}_X)$ fails to be injective.

I don't get why we should care about the spectrum of $f$, as opposed to the point spectrum. In fact, even the point spectrum seems like an "auxiliary" construction to me. The way I see it, what we really want is to understand the "eigenspace function" $\mathrm{Eig}_f : \mathrm{Sub}(X) \leftarrow \mathbb{K}$ into the linear subspaces of $X$ given as follows.

$$x \in \mathrm{Eig}_f(\lambda) \iff f(x) = \lambda x$$

In order to learn things about $\mathrm{Eig}_f$, one strategy would be to first try to find the set of all $\lambda \in \mathbb{K}$ such that $\mathrm{Eig}_f(\lambda)$ has elements beyond $0$. This is precisely the point spectrum of $f$. The hope is that by first finding the point spectrum, we will know for which $\lambda \in \mathbb{K}$ we ought to "look further." This motivates the importance of the point spectrum of $f$, but makes no mention of the spectrum. So:

> **Question.** Why are functional analysts interested in not only the point spectrum of $f$, but also, its spectrum?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was Fourier who first studied what are now known as spectral expansions in order to solve his heat equation. In order to solve a heat equation such as
$$
                    \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial x^{2}}+qu,
$$
where $q$ is a heat source or sink function, Fourier used separation of variables and, essentially, discovered that he could find eigenfunctions of the right side (not Fourier's language) $u_{\lambda}$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$ in order to reduce the problem to discrete and continuous linear combinations of eigenfunctions
$$
                       u(t,x) = \sum_{n} a_{n}e^{-\lambda_{n} t}f_{\lambda_{n}}(x)+\int b(\lambda)e^{-\lambda t}f_{\lambda}(x)d\lambda.
$$
The problem came in how to determine the coefficients $a_{n}$ and $b(\lambda)$ in order to match the initial temperature distribution $u(t,x)=g(x)$
$$
       g(x) = \sum_{n}a_{n}f_{\lambda_{n}}(x)+\int b(\lambda)f_{\lambda}(x)d\lambda.
$$
Cauchy and others correctly identified the proper parameters $\lambda$ in the sums and integrals as singularities of the resolvent operator $(L-\lambda I)^{-1}$, where, in this case,
$$
                               Lf = f''+qf.
$$
Slowly it was realized that one could trade the singularity of the resolvent at $\infty$, say
$$
    -\lim_{\lambda\rightarrow\infty}\lambda(L-\lambda I)^{-1}=I,
$$
for integrals around all of the other singularities in the finite plane. The identity $I$ on the one side of the equation, and integrals around all of the finite singularities on the other side of the equation. That's the required expansion theorem.

The residues of the poles would lead to a discrete series, and a continuous component could be present, normally in the form of a branch cut on the real axis. That would lead to the required expansions
$$
\begin{align}
    f = If & = \sum_{n}\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{C_{n}}\frac{1}{(\lambda I -L)}f \\
            & + \lim_{\delta\downarrow 0}\int_{a}^{b}\frac{1}{(u-i\delta)I-L}-\frac{1}{(u+i\delta)I-L}f\,du
\end{align}
$$
It took a long time to evolve to that final point, but it cemented operator theory as the proper tool for studying such expansions. And it made Complex analysis of the resolvent operator $(\lambda I-L)^{-1}$ through its singularities the fundamental tool of Spectral Theory.

Spectrum $\sigma=\sigma(L)$ is now defined as the set of singularities of the resolvent. Continuous spectrum is thought to give rise to continuous expansions, and discrete spectrum to give rise to sums of expansion terms. And the sum of all such singularities will add to the identity $I$, which is the residue at $\infty$. That's the intuition, but the details are, of course, fierce. And most of the time, closed form limiting expressions and expansions don't work out so nice unless $L$ is selfadjoint. Selfadjoint operators have the peculiar property that poles are of order 1 because
$$
            \|(\lambda I-L)^{-1}\| = \frac{1}{\mbox{dist}(\lambda,\sigma)}.
$$
For bounded operators $L$, it's always true that $\lim_{\lambda\rightarrow\infty}\lambda(\lambda I-A)^{-1}=I$. This gets tricky for unbounded. General operators are tough to fully study with these methods. Higher order poles can occur for the resolvent, corresponding to cyclic subspaces of Jordan type. Sometimes the spectrum is a single point (e.q., quasinilpotent,) and this method gives you nothing. Complications abound. But it's good enough to give you the full Spectral Theorem for bounded and unbounded selfadjoint linear operators.

Comment: I think this is a very nice explanation. Do you know of good references a) for the history on the subject (spectral theory, in particular of self-adjoint operators) b) where the complex-analysis emphasis/viewpoint of spectrum and spectral theory that you indicate is given in more detail?

Comment: @mickep : J. Dieudonne "A History of Functional Analysis" credits Fourier with origin of Spectral Theory. E. C. Titchmarsh focuses on the complex analysis in "Eigenfunction Expansions ...". Titchmarsh gave the first general approach for proving pointwise convergence of general Fourier expansions as I described. General Titchmarsh-Weyl theory focuses on Complex Analysis aspects. Teschl in "Mathematical Methods in Quantum Mechanics" uses a circa 1905 representation theorem for holomorphic functions to prove/study the Spectral Theorem for sefaldjoint operators. See T. Kato "Perturbation Theory".

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm looking forward visiting the department library tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

In applications (typically quantum mechanics) other parts of the spectrum arises naturally.

One such example is a free particle, where the spectrum is purely continuous.

And since the general spectrum arises in applications, one should/might also be interested in studying it in the more abstract setting you describe.

Comment: Okay, but can you elaborate a bit? Suppose $f$ is a bounded linear transform whose spectrum is purely continuous. What does this tell us? How does it help us?

Comment: For example, calculating the spectrum of the Schrödinger operator $-\Delta+V$ (under certain conditions on the electric potential $V$) in $\mathbb{R}^3$ will give you some negative eigenvalues, together with essential spectrum on the positive half line. A typical conclusion is that a particle with low energy is localized due to $V$, while particles with high energy tend to be free (i.e. do not really feel the potential). A good source to read on this subject is the four books by Reed and Simon.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Would you say that Reed and Simon motivate the material particularly well? If so, I may buy it. Also, how accessible is the material? I do not know much physics; the furthest I have gone is an introductory course in quantum mechanics that emphasized Schrodinger's equation.

Comment: It sounds to me that you will not be disappointed. Before buying the four volumes, I would suggest that you have a look in the library. One of the books were used at my university in a course on spectral theory. I hope someone else will give other applications/motivations where different types of spectra is involved.

Comment: "do not really feel the potential" is quite imprecise. They do feel the potential, but have enough energy to escape to infinity.

Comment: @Ruslan imprecise, indeed. I agree with your correction completely.